# Bridge virtual interface into physical network?

Tags: linux, networking

Like  the diagram below, the physical network is 192.168.99.0/24. `veth0` lives inside a separate network-namespace. I want it to directly connect into the physical network, thus `node1` and `veth0` can talk to each other through physical network without any NATs.

[image]

What I've tried is:

- create a linux bridge br0
- connect veth1 to br0
- connect eth0 (physical NIC of node2) to br0

Turns out, if we ping from 192.168.99.3 to 192.168.99.1, then `arp` packets come from `veth0`, traverse through `veth1` to `br0`, and then be broadcasted to `node2`'s `eth0`, and finally get received by `node1`'s `eth0`.

Howerver, when `node1` replies, packet's dested to `veth0`'s mac address won't be received by node2's `eth0` (mac mismatch I guess), thus `veth0` won't get arp reply packets and ping fails.

So, if I'm not understanding this wrong, can anybody gives me any ideas on how to make this bridge network happen?

**UPDATE**

I rebuild this test environment on bare metal machines, turns out everything works fine. Maybe something wrong with virtualbox networking.

Comment: This should work in theory, as bridging eth0 would switch it to promiscuous mode and disable MAC filtering.

Comment: @grawity Unfortunately I didn't make this work. :(  Can you take a try?

Comment: I just got this working on KVMs by using two veths on the bridge, one in the container namespace with the container's IP and one not, with the host IP.  No IP on the bridge itself.  Other nodes on the network see individual IPs and MACs.  Biggest surprise was that moving things into namespaces erases the IP and such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do sounds correct, but there is an important number of small details (cleaning the previous configuration, bringing all interfaces up, creating a new network namespace from which to use one end of the *veth* pair), that I am not sure you have done everything correctly. In particular, I do not know whether you realized that you will need to *dhcp* (if you do not use a static IP address) the end of the *veth* pair inside the new network namespace .

So, in order to give you the full details, I will tell you how I do this, using *veth*'s: first I clean the current configuration,

```
# systemctl stop network-manager
# ip link set dev usb0 down   
# ip addr flush dev usb0
```

then I create the *veth* pair, and then I put my ethernet interface (here it is called *usb0*) and one end of the *veth* pair into a bridge called *br1*:

```
# ip link add veth-a1 type veth peer name veth-b1
# ip link set veth-a1 up
# ip link add br1 type bridge
# ip link set veth-a1 master br1
# ip link set usb0 master br1
# ip link set usb0 up
# ip link set br1 up
```

Notice that it is important to bring the different interfaces **up**; then I start *dhclient on the bridge*:

```
# dhclient br1
.....
bound to 192.168.11.98 -- renewal in 16650 seconds.
```

Now I transfer the other end of the *veth* pair to the new network namespace, called *ns1*, and create an *xterm* inside the new network namespace:

```
# ip netns add ns1
# ip link set veth-b1 netns ns1
# ip netns exec ns1 xterm &
```

so that, from the *xterm* I can bring up the other end of the *veth* pair and start *dhclient* on it.

```
# ip link set dev veth-b1 up
# dhclient veth-b1
```

To test this, just *ping www.debian.org*, and you will check both the connection and the fact that DNSes are imported from your primary network namespace automatically.

It would have been much easier with a *macvlan*, though..,

Comment: I've followed your step and tested on a virtualbox machine, finally failed. I can't ping br1's IP from another virtualbox machine, and can't `dhclient veth-br1` either. Guess usb0 won't accept a packet whose dest mac address is veth-br1.

Comment: I've test my setup method directly on bare metal machines, turns out everything works fine. Guess there's something wrong with the virtualbox networking.